# Stata: Edit each element of a global (which contains a list of variables)

Tags: global, stata

This is probably just a short syntax question. I have:

```
clear all
macro drop _all
global variables var1 var2
```

and I want

```
global means m_var1 m_var2
```

which I have generated elsewhere. The goal is to use both globals in a Mundlak regression (like `reg depvar $variables $means` and not having to calculate/include the means by hand for different specifications. My idea was something along the lines of:

```
global means "m_`variables'"
```

but that simply ignores the `variables` global. Again, sorry for the R-think...

**Edit:** My strategy: I am trying to write a program which runs models (Mundlak/Chamberlain random effects logit, see Wooldridges Panel book 2nd ed p. 487) on several distinct lists of variables and returns graphs of regression  results. This should be done such that I only have to change the globals/locals specifying these variables in the beginning. Thus, I need to have code that creates time averages of the globals and uses these and the original global in the logit specification.

Comment: Your last line of code seems confused on the difference between locals and globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced your general strategy is a good one, but I don't have information on the issue you face, so I won't comment much more.

I'll state that using `local`s is a better idea if you can spare the `global`s, and that you can redefine the contents of a macro using a loop:

```
clear all
set more off

local variables var1 var2

// original
local means "m_`variables'"

// loop
local means2
foreach v of local variables {
    local means2 `means2' m_`v'
}

display "`means'"
display "`means2'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Concerning my strategy: I also have the feeling that I'm kind of muddling my way from workaround to workaround. Maybe my edit helps? Could you elaborate or provide a source on why locals are better? If I include `macro drop _all`, I can use chunks of code one at a time and have no further disadvantages from using globals, correct?

Comment: `local`s disappear once the program finishes its run, so you don't 
inadvertantly polute your name space. The use of `global`s may create problems 
that are more difficult to detect and solve than the those caused by using a
`local`. It's Stata's recommendation: "Global macros are rarely used, and when 
they are used, it is typically for communication between programs. You should 
never use a global macro where a local macro would suffice". Source:
**[U] 18.3.10 Advanced global macro manipulation**. More information can be
found in other sections of **[U] 18.3 Macros** and in **[P] macro**.